# Can custom xml(containing UI tools e.g Labels, Textfields, Buttons) can be replaced by .xib's xml(As we know that .xib is an xml file)

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I want to create dynamic layout. The custom xml file will be downloaded from server and will contain all necessary information to draw UI tool(Buttons, labels).Is it possible in iOS programming? I need your opinion on the same.

Answer (score 0):

It must be possible. Just make sure you have the template right. Right click on any xib and look at the source for a reference

Comment: It can be done programatically. But it is a bit tricky. That is how these cross platform apps work.